# Is there any obvious reason this won't render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, render

I'm pulling in an array of objects and mapping them to another component to be rendered.

```
  renderRatings(){
        if(this.props.ratings.length > 0){
            return this.props.ratings.map(rating => {
                <Rating 
                    id={rating.id}
                    title={rating.title}
                    value={rating.value}
                />
            });
        }
    }
```

This is where I render the rendering function.

```
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.renderRatings()}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the component I'm trying to populate and have rendered.

```
class Rating extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("props equal:", this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card darken-1" key={this.props._id}>
                <div className="card-content">
                <span className="card-title">{this.props.title}</span>
                <p>{this.props.value}</p>
                <button>Edit</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.deleteRating(this.props._id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

  export default connect({ deleteRating })(Rating);
```

No errors are being thrown, but when the page loads, the surrounding menu comes up, and the fetch request returns an array and supposedly maps it to the 'Rating' component, but no mapped Rating cards appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your map,  you're not returning the Rating etc... because you used { to define a code block, you have to type return. And since it's multi-line, use parens to mark the start and end of the Rating component.

```
return this.props.ratings.map(rating => {
                <Rating 
                    id={rating.id}
                    title={rating.title}
                    value={rating.value}
                />
```

needs to be

```
return this.props.ratings.map(rating => {
                return (<Rating 
                    id={rating.id}
                    title={rating.title}
                    value={rating.value}
                />)
```

Comment: Oh. Duhhhh. Thanks! That fixed the problem ;D